# Discord.py: How can I get all the posts and who made them from a channel?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to get all the posts from a channel. Can you please help me? I'm searching but the only thing I found is guild.text_channels, but I can't find how to get all the posts and who made them.

Thank you for any reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async for ... in channel.history()` [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history).

Example: Prints the last 100 messages and their author.

```py
for channel in guild.text_channels:
    async for message in channel.history(limit=100):
        print(message.content, 'by', str(message.author))
```